# Is it possible to abstract over kinds in Idris?

Tags: idris

I'm going through Type Driven Development with Idris, learning about how to define functions with variable numbers of arguments. I got a little ambitious and wanted to write a `mapN` function that would map a function of `(n : Nat)` arguments onto `n` values of some `Applicative` type.

Investigating this problem led me to think that it was probably not possible without at least also providing the types of the arguments to the function. This led me to try to write a function that would take a `Nat` and a variable number of `Type` arguments and return a function type as if you'd strung arrows between the types. As in:

```
Arrows 0 Int = Int
Arrows 1 Int String = Int -> String
```

Here was my best attempt, which doesn't work:

```
Arrows : (n : Nat) -> (a : Type) -> Type
Arrows Z a = a
Arrows (S k) a = f where
  f : Type -> Type
  f b = Arrows k a -> b
```

Unfortunately neither of the type signatures make sense, because sometimes I want the function to return a `Type` and sometimes it returns `Type -> Type` and sometimes it returns `Type -> Type -> Type` and so forth. I thought this would be roughly as straightforward as writing any other function with a variable number of arguments, but it seems that because those arguments are types, it might be impossible.

Looking around for an answer, I came across [Kind Polymorphism](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism.html) enabled by -XPolyKinds in Haskell which seems to allow what's needed here. Am I correct in thinking that this is what Idris is missing for this to be possible? Or is there some other way to do this in Idris?

Comment: Could you clarify your mapN? Per google I find that people use this for `map2 : (i -> a) -> (i -> b) -> f i -> f (a,b)`, `map2 : (a -> a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, `map2 : (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> fc`. Based on your idea I believe you want the last one?

Comment: @xash yes, the `mapN` I was looking for is a generalization of `map`, `map2`, `map3`, etc, where the `map2` that I'm referring to has basically the last type signature that you listed, though I think an `Applicative` interface constraint is required (`map2 : Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`). I still don't know what the type signature for `mapN` would be, but what I'm imagining would allow me to write this:

    `mapN 2 MkPair (Just 1) (Just "foo")`

...which would be equivalent to:

    `MkPair <$> Just 1 <*> Just "foo"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `Arrows` has a dependent type, as you've noted:

- `Arrows 0 : Type -> Type`
- `Arrows 1 : Type -> Type -> Type`
- `Arrows 2 : Type -> Type -> Type -> Type`
- ...

Note that the appearance of `Type` here changes nothing. Specifically, note that `Type : Type`, `(Type -> Type) : Type`, and so on. It could be `Int`. It could be `n ** Vect n (Fin n)`. In other words, there is no distinction between types and kinds.

So:

```
arrowsTy : Nat -> Type
arrowsTy Z = Type
arrowsTy (S k) = Type -> arrowTy k
```

can be used to define `Arrows`'s type.

And then you can define `Arrows`:

```
Arrows : (n : Nat) -> Type -> arrowTy n
Arrows Z a = a
Arrows (S k) a = compose (\b => a -> b) . Arrows k
  where compose : { n : Nat } -> (Type -> Type) -> arrowsTy n -> arrowsTy n
     -- compose is used to modify the eventual result of the recursion
        compose { n = Z } g f = g f
        compose { n = S k } g f = compose g . f
```

And, if you merge `compose` into `Arrows`, you can get another version:

```
Arrows' : (Type -> Type) -> (n : Nat) -> Type -> arrowTy n
Arrows' finalize Z x = finalize x
Arrows' finalize (S k) x = Arrows' (finalize . (\r => x -> r)) k
Arrows : (n : Nat) -> Type -> arrowTy n
Arrows = Arrows' id
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great!